# Check date, region before uploading file on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a scenario where before uploading file, I want to check if the date and region are same then it should prompt a javascript message that

***"file with same date and region is already their, do you want to override it ?"***

If user clicks yes, then the old file data should get into the history table and the new uploaded file should get into the main table.

My table name is as follows:-

**WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr**   --- Main table

**WMS_Future_Del_Order_trl**    --- Main table

History table

**WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr_h**   -- history table

**WMS_Future_Del_Order_trl_h**   -- history table

Here is my HTML :-

```
<td valign="middle" width="20%">
                    <input id="TxtEdate" runat="server" maxlength="20" style="width: 65%; background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-position: bottom right; border: solid 1px #ACACAC" type="text" />
                    <cc3:Calendar ID="CalEntryDt" runat="server" DatePickerMode="true" TextBoxId="TxtEdate"
                        DatePickerImagePath="../Images/icon2.gif" CultureName="en-GB">
                    </cc3:Calendar>
                </td>
                 <td align="left" width="10%">
                    <span class="xy8">Region :</span>
                </td>
                 <td valign="left" width="40%">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegion" runat="server" Style="width: 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-position: bottom right; border: solid 1px #ACACAC; font-family: Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,sans-serif">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
```

Also see my code behind:-

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
    dtExcel.Clear();
    string StrCount = String.Empty;
    string connString = "";
    HttpPostedFile File = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
    string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string Filename = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, path.Length - path.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1);
    path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Excels/" + "/" + Filename.ToString());

    File.SaveAs(path);
    if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet 1$]";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    conn.Close();
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter daExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    daExcel.Fill(dtExcel);
    conn.Close();

    DataTable DtMain = CF.ExecuteDT("select Tran_type, Order_Date from WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr where Tran_type = '" + CmbTypeOfAsn.SelectedValue + "' and Order_Date = convert(datetime,'" + TxtEdate.Value + "',103)");

    StringBuilder StrPubBldg = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(StrPubBldg);

    string ExcelfileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

    xw.WriteStartElement("DocumentElement");
    {
        xw.WriteStartElement("WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr");
        xw.WriteElementString("Comp_mkey", "0");
        xw.WriteElementString("FDepartment_ID", "W");
        xw.WriteElementString("FModule_id", "W");
        xw.WriteElementString("Tran_type", CmbTypeOfAsn.SelectedValue);
        xw.WriteElementString("Doc_no", "1");
        xw.WriteElementString("Doc_date", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        xw.WriteElementString("Order_Date", TxtEdate.Value);
        xw.WriteElementString("Import_Filename", Filename);
        xw.WriteElementString("Save_File_Name_Path", Server.MapPath("~/FutureDelivery/") + ExcelfileName + ".xls");
        xw.WriteElementString("Note_Remarks", txtRemarks.Text);
        xw.WriteElementString("User_id", "1");
        xw.WriteElementString("U_DateTime", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        xw.WriteElementString("Delete_flag", "N");
        xw.WriteEndElement();

        string STRLine_Id = "0";
        string STRItem_Mkey = "1";
        string STRItem_Code = "2";
        string STRItem_Desc = "3";
        string STRLot_Batch_No = "4";
        string STRExp_Dt = "";
        string STRBx_Bg = "6";
        string STRNet_Wgt = "7";
        string STRQty = "8";
        string STRNo_of_Pallets = "9";
        DataTable ParaDt = CF.ExecuteDT("select * from WMS_Mapping_Para_Table");
        for (int i = 0; i < ParaDt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Line_Id")
            {
                STRLine_Id = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Item_Mkey")
            {
                STRItem_Mkey = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Item_Code")
            {
                STRItem_Code = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Item_Desc")
            {
                STRItem_Desc = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Lot_Batch_No")
            {
                STRLot_Batch_No = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Exp_Dt")
            {
                STRExp_Dt = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Qty")
            {
                STRQty = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Bx_Bg")
            {
                STRBx_Bg = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Net_Wgt")
            {
                STRNet_Wgt = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }

        }
        if (dtExcel.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                xw.WriteStartElement("WMS_Future_Del_Order_Trl");
                xw.WriteElementString("Sr_No", (i + 1).ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Line_Id", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRLine_Id)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Item_Mkey", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRItem_Mkey)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Item_Code", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRItem_Code)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Item_Desc", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRItem_Desc)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Lot_Batch_No", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRLot_Batch_No)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Exp_Dt", Convert.ToDateTime(dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRExp_Dt)].ToString()).ToShortDateString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Qty", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRQty)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Bx_Bg", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRBx_Bg)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Net_Wgt", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRNet_Wgt)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("No_of_Pallets", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRNo_of_Pallets)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Creation_Date", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
                xw.WriteElementString("Update_Date", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
                xw.WriteElementString("Created_By", "1");
                xw.WriteElementString("Updated_By", "1");
                xw.WriteElementString("User_id", "1");
                xw.WriteElementString("U_DateTime", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
                xw.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
        xw.Close();
        String strretmkey = InsertUpdateDelete.InsertUpdateDeleteCls.InsertUpdateDelete_sql(Hid_Mode.Value, Convert.ToInt32(Hid_MKey.Value), "WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr", "MKEY", "FD", StrPubBldg.ToString());
        DataTable dt = CF.ExecuteDT("Select Tran_type,DATEPART(yyyy,U_DateTime) AS U_DateTime,DATEPART(mm,U_DateTime) AS U_DateTime from WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr where mkey ='" + strretmkey + "'");
        StrDocNo = strretmkey + '/' + dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() + '/' + dt.Rows[0][2].ToString() + dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();

        ExcelfileName = StrDocNo.ToString().Replace("/", "_");
        string strPathval = Server.MapPath("~/FutureDelivery/") + ExcelfileName + ".xls";
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/FutureDelivery/") + ExcelfileName + ".xls");

        CF.ExecuteQuerry("update WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr set Doc_no ='" + StrDocNo + "', Save_File_Name_Path ='" + strPathval + "' where mkey=" + strretmkey + "");

        lblDocNo.Text = StrDocNo.ToString();
        Hid_MKey.Value = strretmkey;
    }

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessScript", "alert('Record saved successfully.');", true);
    FunGridBind();

    btnSave.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: What is your issue? what have tried so far?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed:  I want idea of how to start this coding.. any idea will make me proceed ahead

Comment: Umm i think `Stackoverflow` is not for ideas.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed: I know, but i m confused how to start this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use stored procedure.

1)First check where the given date and region exist in the table or not using `select`

2)If exist means invoke java script message. else store the data into Main table

3)If they click `yes`(javascript message)

-Select the row and pass that selected values to history table write `insert` query and story it

-Then Use `Update` query in Main table and store new upload file